# Spring Boot - Gradle - Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, gradle, directory

I am new to SpringBoot and trying to build a basic hello world application with SpringBoot and gradle in eclipse. 
In eclipse, when I create a gradle project , it adds src/main/java folder but I don't see a src/main/resources folder. is this something that needs to be added manually or do I need to change some setting to get the folder structure created? I am trying to create a simple JSP and need the web-inf and properties folders for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://start.spring.io/  to create your Spring boot project , This will generate proper folder structure

Comment: Thanks. I manually created the folder structure last night. will try this too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that ur trying to build one spring boot application from scratch. You dont really need to do build one from scratch when srping provides spring boot boiler plate which is very handy and easy to use. https://start.spring.io/

Few things you need to know when ur starting a spring boot project. 1.application.properties file contains all the configuration related date.Wondering how to read this property from java class below code can help

```
Java class
@Configuration
public class JMSSQSConfig {
@Value("${queue.endpoint}")
private String endpoint;

application.properties file
#AWS Endpoint
queue.endpoint=https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/
```

Now spring boot reads this value dynamically from application.properties file.

Above link also provides you the way u want to build ur project gradle/maveen.

Above boiler plate has testing frame work assosiated with it too.. It just makes work easy.

Check this link https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Comment: Thanks. I manually created the folder structure and that has worked too but will definitely check this out for my practice.